# Clickhouse: is there a way to set up sampling on an existing MergeTree that doesnt have a primary key in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, sql-like, sampling, clickhouse

I want to do random sampling on this table I have, it contains data that registers users' session activity. So there is a userid, a sessionid, timestamps also other general data. Because of how it was organized, there isn't a single column that is unique since a user can have multiple sessions or a session can be accessed by multiple users, etc.

there are around 300M rows in this table and I wanted to be able to sample it. However, looking at the documentation, it looks like I have to set a hashing key or a sampling key, is it possible to do that when my columns are unique? or is it possible to hash it over multiple columns?

I have a query such as

```
select * from table order by rand() limit (select toInt32(count(*)/100) from table)
```

but it's too demanding to run over the 300M rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible to hash it over multiple columns

```
SELECT cityHash64('axx', 20)

┌─cityHash64('axx', 20)─┐
│   6142436227093532237 │
└───────────────────────┘
```

Sampling is hard thing to implement properly, please read this https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/sampling-example